# How to run a npm package in CLI?

Tags: json, csv, ubuntu, npm

I want to use json2csv inUbuntu, but can't figure out how do I call it. Sorry it's my first use of npm. =(

I installed npm from repo, then installed json2csv like they [recommended](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#how-to-use), and I confused what to do to make it legit [command](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#command-line-interface) for my system, or how to call it using path. =(

Comment: Type node in the command prompt. Then u can use node to call the library that you have downloaded

Comment: @qamar, I installed nodejs, but it didn't help. Says it json2csv isn't defined.

man node:
NAME
       ax25-node - Node front end for AX.25, NET/ROM, Rose and TCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `json2csv` **command** in your PATH, you need to install the package globally:

`npm install -g json2csv`

Now you should be able to use `json2csv` as a command.

If that doesn't work, you need to ensure that the `bin` directory that `npm` is installing to is in your PATH:

`PATH=${PATH}:$(npm get prefix)/bin`

If *that* doesn't work, follow up here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Globally; I didn't know about it, and it weren't stated on my way. Sad that the package didn't work for me. Sometime unmaintained soft is good for a long time.
Sorry I can't vote up. =( 
I don't see a remove command there. Does everything installed is forever? =)

Comment: You can uninstall packages from the local space:

`npm rm json2csv`

Or you can just remove the whole `node_modules` subtree:

`rm -fr node_modules`